# How can I send HTTP requests without using Indy or WinINet?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm looking for lightweight alternatives to IdHTTP for HTTP requests. Preferably ones that don't use WinINet. I need to send a request to a website I own (so I can configure any settings that may be required).

Comment: So, WinINet is too high-level (too restrictive)?

Comment: What's wrong with using `TIdHTTP`?

Comment: Without a definition for "lightweight", this isn't much of a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For maximum amount of control and least anount of overhead, just use the WinSock API directly and send your own HTTP requests manually.  Read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for details about the HTTP protocol.

Comment: ... And most amount of code you write yourself. Don't forget to code your own TCP/IP stack, as relying on the windows DLLs is bad (or else we'd be using WinHttp).  I agree about not using WinInet, but WinHttp is the sane approach.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really know what you're doing, I wouldn't recommend doing HTTP stuff too low-level.

Go to a command prompt, and type:

```
telnet www.yoursite.com 80
```

Wait until you're connected. Now type

```
GET /
```

Ok, that's easy.

But it gets more complicated really quick after this. You'll have to parse headers, deal with redirects, timeouts, caching, proxies, etc.
With the most naive single-threaded implementation, your application will probably freeze until your download has finished.

You might be able to do what you need to do in your application, but as a generic HTTP client, your implementation will suck, unless you'll spend a lot of time on it to get things right.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SynapseLib](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php). Still, I'm not sure if it's using WinInet or not.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to import MSXML2_TLB and use CoServerXmlHTTPRequest.Create, especially if I need XML anyway in the same project.